# Compilation Error while creating jobs in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am learning jobs in oracle.I am new to this topic.So,I created a table to store sysdate.

```
create table offc.MYTEST(
CREATED_ON DATE
)
```

I created the procedure as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE offc.myproc AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MYTEST(CREATED_ON)
VALUES (sysdate);
commit;
END myproc;
/
```

I created the jobs as:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
job_name = ‘My_job’,
job_type = ‘STORED_PROCEDURE’,
job_action = ‘MYPROC’,
start_date = sysdate,
repeat_interval = ‘FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=5',
end_date =’1/2/2020 9:53:05 PM’,
auto_drop = FALSE,
comments = ‘My new job’);
END;
/
```

I got error as:

```
Error at line 1
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
```

Also,I am getting error as:

[image]

I dont know but the red markers are also seen.What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, I think i get it. It seems you have copied it from somewhere so your single quotes are not Oracle supported and they are being treated as unsupported characters. I have created it again after typing all single quotes again and converting all `=` to `=>`-

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
job_name => 'My_job',
job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
job_action => 'MYPROC',
start_date => sysdate,
repeat_interval => 'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=5',
end_date => '02-Jan-2020 09:53:05 PM',
auto_drop => FALSE,
comments => 'My new job');
END;
/
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c8194d9ab3b7f41a3d4ca1d332a0a772) is the fiddle. Since I do not have the privilege to create job on fiddle, You are seeing that error there.

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59567073/how-to-execute-the-jobs-in-oracle