# How to execute the jobs in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a simple job which is:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
job_name => 'offc.My_job1',
job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
job_action => 'offc.MYPROC',
start_date => sysdate,
repeat_interval => 'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=5',
end_date => '02-Jan-2020 10:29:05 PM',
auto_drop => FALSE,
comments => 'My new job');
END;
/
```

Now,I tried to run the job using:

```
EXEC DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE(‘My_job1’);
```

I got error as:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "‘" when expecting one of the following:

   ( ) - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   table continue avg count current exists max min prior sql
   stddev sum variance execute multiset the both leading
   trailing forall merge year month day hour minute second
   timezone_hour timezone_minute timezone_region timezone_abbr
   time timestamp interval date
   <a string literal with character set specification>
```

Also,I tried,

```
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable (name => 'My_job1');
```

I got error as:

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Both of them are not working.Why is not my job being runned?

Comment: Please do not post any further questions before you have checked that you are using only simple ASCII quotes in your code.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - this is the second question the OP has asked today in which the problem is caused by the code containing a non-standard quote character, and the  solution is to replace it with the correct quote character. Personally I don't consider that "showing effort" but you're entitled to set your bar as low as you like .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are again facing issue of the single quote.

```
EXEC DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE(‘My_job1’);
```

Here quotes `‘` is not supported by oracle. It should be `'` .

```
EXEC DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE('My_job1');
```

Cheers!!